# SQL Query to Return True or False from left joing table

Tags: mysql

Table ClientServices is Left Joined to Table Customers

`Table Customers`

```
SysRef  FullName
1       ABC
2       RST
3       XYZ
```

`Table Client Services`

```
ClientSysRef  ServiceID
1             10
2             14
2             7
3             8
```

Where each Service ID corresponds to a particular service being offered. For example ServiceID 7 is IT, ServiceID 8 is Accounts, Service ID 10 is Marketing, ServiceID 14 is HR. I need to find away to return True if either ServiceID is found for the particular client or false if Not. Required Result;

```
SysRef  FullName  IT    Accounts    Marketing    HR
1       ABC       False False       True         False
2       RST       True  False       False        True
3       XYZ       False True        False        False
```

Is this possible with SQL? Could someone please guide me? Thanks

Current Result;

```
SysRef  FullName  IT    Accounts    Marketing    HR
1       ABC       False False       True         False
2       RST       True  False       False        False
2       RST       False False       False        True
3       XYZ       False True        False        False
```

Comment: CASE WHEN x = 'a' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END IT, CASE WHEN x = 'b'...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [Control Flow Functions:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html)

```
SELECT 
    SysRef,
    IF(ServiceID = 7, 'TRUE', 'FALSE') as IT,
    ... #The same for the others
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.sysref,c.fullname,case when d.serviceID = 7 then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end as IT,
case when d.serviceID = 8 then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end as Accounts,
case when d.serviceID = 10 then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end as Marketing,
case when d.serviceID = 14 then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end as HR from customers c join client_services d on c.sysref = d.clientsysref;
```

Comment: Thanks @Priyanshu. When the condition meets more than one service it is being displayed in separate rows. Is there away to display all in one row? Eg from the required result above for client with SysRef 2

Comment: result table added above 'Current Result'

Comment: how about adding ''group by c.sysref''  at the end of the query.
I am not sure ,Lets give it a try.

Comment: Afraid not. "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference."